# What is the most appropriate way to structure relative paths using a MERN stack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am deploying a MERN application and am looking for guidance on what the best approach for structuring relative paths for my API vs React routes. Below is a subset of my routes for both. My relative routes are duplicating the folder structure and I am uncertain how to fix this.

**User Routes**

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.get("/api/users", UserController.index);
...
};
```

**User Actions**

```
export const fetchUsers = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get("api/users");
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USERS, payload: response.data });
};
```

The issue occurs when I call the `fetchUsers` action from the `/users` React route. The relative route directs the request over to `/users/api/users` when I would like it to send to `/api/users`.

### UPDATE

I solved the issue by instantiating an `axios` object with a baseurl for my api calls.

**Axios Instance, API**

```
import axios from "axios";

let URL = "";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  URL = "herokuapp/api";
} else {
  URL = "http://localhost:3000";
}
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: URL
});
```

**Update User Actions**

```
export const fetchUsers = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await rumbanroll.get("api/users");
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USERS, payload: response.data });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your APIs are hosted on the same domain as your client, then you can just make use of absolute urls to hit the API instead of relative urls which you have written in your axios url like

```
export const fetchUsers = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get("/api/users"); // notice the / before api
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USERS, payload: response.data });
};
```